# How to populate from database to different field using Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I'm using mongoose and sometimes I need to populate a linked document.  The problem is when I populate it, it fills the document id field (`listingID`) with a document and if later I try to use that document id field, it can cause issues.  I've come up with a workaround that takes the document saved in the document id field and saved it to a different field (`listing`) then saves the id of that document back to the document id field.  See the example below.

My question is, is there a better way to do this?  Does mongoose have a way to do this already that I don't know about?  If not, is there a way to add a function like this to the schema so I don't need to write this every time I use `populate()`?

```
let reservations = await Reservation.find({})
    .populate("listingID")
    .lean();
reservations = reservations.map(reservation => {
    reservation.listing = reservation.listingID;
    reservation.listingID = reservation.listing._id;
    return reservation;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see my example code.

```js
 
      (req, res) => {
        const errors = {};

        Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
          .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
          .then(profile => {
            if (!profile) {
              errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user';
              return res.status(404).json(errors);
            }
            res.json(profile);
          })
          .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
      }
```

this example If you get anyone's profile, you have to profiles contents and user data.

Now you can use populate.

So if you connect one collection and then another collection, you can use it.

I send example Schema

```js
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        
        // Create Schema
        const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
          },
          handle: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            max: 40
          },
          company: {
            type: String
          },
          website: {
            type: String
          },
          location: {
            type: String
          },
          status: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          skills: {
            type: [String],
            required: true
          },
          bio: {
            type: String
          },
          githubusername: {
            type: String
          },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
          }
        });
    
    module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

this example profiles connect user's data.